# Enable Linum Mode for all files (with extension) but not other buffers?

Tags: linum-mode, global-mode

In my `init.el` file I have the following line: `(global-linum-mode 1)`.  I want `linum-mode` enabled for every file, but not for other buffers.  I.e. Is there a way to enable linum mode globally for all buffers with an extension?

Frequently my buffer list looks like

```
file.js  js2-mode
init.el   Emacs-Lisp
ansi-term Term:
```

In this case I would like to have it enabled for everything but `ansi-term`. Is this possible?

Furthermode, just for ansi term I tried the following:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode -1)))
```

But even that did not work.  If someone could tell me why that would be great but enabling it just for files would be ideal.

Thanks

Comment: I think a little differently than everyone else, perhaps because I'm not a programmer.  Personally, I would set up a regexp function in the initialization of the minor-mode that checks the file extension -- e.g., `buffer-file-name` -- against a list of either desired or excluded file extensions.  Depending upon the match or exclusion, I would let the minor-mode continue initializing or deactivate at that point.  Here is the regexp function:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20343715/2112489  Perhaps people just don't like modifying the source-code -- a sacred/holy thing -- not sure though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Enable Linum Mode for all files [...] but not other buffers?

How about:

```el
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'linum-mode)
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution covering nearly every file would be making use of the fact that nearly all buffers for these are derived from `text-mode` and `prog-mode`:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'linum-mode)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'linum-mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [linum-off.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/linum-off.el) file by Matthew Fidler should be what you are looking for.

Here is a copy of his code:

```
(require 'linum)

(defcustom linum-disabled-modes-list '(eshell-mode wl-summary-mode compilation-mode org-mode text-mode dired-mode doc-view-mode image-mode)
  "* List of modes disabled when global linum mode is on"
  :type '(repeat (sexp :tag "Major mode"))
  :tag " Major modes where linum is disabled: "
  :group 'linum
)
(defcustom linum-disable-starred-buffers 't
  "* Disable buffers that have stars in them like *Gnu Emacs*"
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'linum)

(defun linum-on ()
  "* When linum is running globally, disable line number in modes defined in `linum-disabled-modes-list'. Changed by linum-off. Also turns off numbering in starred modes like *scratch*"

  (unless (or (minibufferp)
              (member major-mode linum-disabled-modes-list)
              (string-match "*" (buffer-name))
              (> (buffer-size) 3000000)) ;; disable linum on buffer greater than 3MB, otherwise it's unbearably slow
    (linum-mode 1)))

(provide 'linum-off)
```