# How to enable mode for all files

Tags: init-file

What do I put in my `init` to enable a mode for all files?

Say I want to have `auto-fill-mode` enabled at all times.

I've seen [this
post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21504/enable-linum-mode-for-all-files-with-extension-but-not-other-buffers)
and some others, but all are focused on a specific task. I'd like to document
a general solution to a common search that uses best practices.

Comment: [define-globalized-minor-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html#Defining-Minor-Modes) perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the mode.

In your case you can do:

```
(auto-fill-mode 1)
```